# Segmentation fault(core dumped) - cPointers [C]

Tags: c

I was assigned with a task of completing an assignment in C, without being taught C. (I have been learning Java) I am not sure how to fix this error nor do I know what the error means.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//int mystrcmp(char * s, char * t);

int  main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

// #1 Prints out cmd line arguments

int i;
for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
{

    printf("%s\n",argv[i]);

}

printf("\n"); //Spaceholder

// #2  String Compare
printf("%s %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
printf("Returned Value: %d\n", mystrcmp(argv[1], argv[2]));
//mystrcmp(argv[1],argv[2]);


// #3 String Concatenate

printf("\n"); //Spaceholder
printf("String Concatenate: %s\n", mystrcat(argv[1]));

// #4 String Copy

printf("\n"); //Spaceholder
//  printf("String Copy: %s\n" , mystrcpy(argv[1]));

}
                     ///////////
                    //Methods//
                   ///////////

/* srtcmp: return < 0 if s < t, 0 if s==t, > 0 if s > t */

int mystrcmp(char * s, char * t)
{

int i;
for(i = 0; s[i] && s[2]; ++i)
{
    if (s[i] == t[i] || (s[i]) == t[i])
       continue;
    else
       break;
}

if (s[i] == t[i])
    return 0;
if ((s[i]) < (t[i])) 
    return -1;
        return 1;

}
 mystrcat(char *dest, char *source)
{
    int a = 0;

    while(*(dest + a) != '\0')
    {
            a++;
    }

    int b = 0;

    while(*(source + a) != '\0')
    {
             *(dest + a) = *(source + b);
             a++;
             b++;
    }

}  

 mystrcpy(char * s, char * dest)
 {
   while((*s++ = *dest++)!= '\0')
    ; 
   return *dest;
 }
```

I am assuming the error is coming from my mystrcat.

Comment: Your posted code should not compile. Can you please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `mystrcat()` takes 2 arguments, but you're only passing 1.

Comment: `mystrcat()` requires the string that `dest` points to to have enough space for the `source` string to be appended. You haven't allocated a string that has enough space for `source+dest`.

Comment: When I change it to `mystrcat(argv[1], argv[2])` it just returns null.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while(*(source + a) != '\0')
```

should be

```
    while(*(source + b) != '\0')
```

Comment: I'd advise getting rid of the `*(x+y)`-silliness. `x[y]` exists for a reason, it's much more readable.

Comment: Any idea why it returns null?